# I want to call a function when carousel image is changed by the navigation in lightbox2 Plugin

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I'm working with the Lightbox2 plugin and want to execute a function whenever the carousel image changes via navigation. How can I achieve this? Looking for suggestions or code snippets to implement this feature effectively. Thanks in advance!

I tried going their official documentation but i coudnt find the solution.